# Calculate percentage clicked in a HTML5 canvas radial progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have created a circular progress bar like this

[image]

I can load a certain percentage by sending it with java-script but I can't figure out how to calculate the percentage that a user has clicked if he clicks on the black/green part of the circle.

How would one calculate the percentage?

Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here's one way to convert a click angle into a percentage:**

- Use `Math.atan2` to calculate the angle of the mouse versus the centerpoint.
- Normalize that angle within 0-PI*2 radians: `(angle+PI*2)%(PI*2)`.
- Calculate that angle's percentage of a full circle: `normalizedAngle/(PI*2)`.
- That's your percentage!

**Illustration: Note that 0% is at the circle's 3 o'clock position**

[image][image]

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;
var $canvas = $("#canvas");
var canvasOffset = $canvas.offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX = $canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY = $canvas.scrollTop();

var isDown = false;
var startX;
var startY;

var cx = 150;
var cy = 150;
var radius = 75;
var PI = Math.PI;
var PI2 = PI * 2;

ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.font = '24px verdana';

draw(50, 50);

function draw(x, y) {

  var dx = x - cx;
  var dy = y - cy;
  var endAngle = (Math.atan2(dy, dx) + PI2) % PI2;
  var pct = parseInt(endAngle / PI2 * 100);

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, 0, PI2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, 0, endAngle);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'forestgreen';
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.fillText(pct + '%', cx - 15, cy + 8);

}



function handleMouseDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
  mY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

  draw(mX, mY);

}

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e) {
  handleMouseDown(e);
});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Click on the canvas to set a percentage.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to do this using trig, since I think it's easy to remember and use.  You just have to be able to find the top of the circle's coordinates, and the center's coordinates and know it's radius.  And you have to be able to determine the click's distance to both of those.  So offsets might have to be used. You can modify this code to suit your particular needs.

If you have the coordinates of the click, the circle's center, and the top of the circle, you can find the distance between all three points.  Having the lengths of each side of a triangle is enough information to find all of the angles it as well.

The only angle you are concerned about is the one in the center.  You can use that one, compared to whether you clicked passed the middle of not, to find the percentage of the circle.

Here are some sources:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33709/get-angle-in-radians-given-a-point-on-a-circle
http://snipplr.com/view/47207/distance-between-two-points/
http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-triangles.html MATH is Fun!

Here is a working example: http://jsbin.com/hopak/1/edit

```
$('#circle').click(function (e) { //Relative ( to its parent) mouse position 
    var posX = $(this).position().left,
        posY = $(this).position().top,
     radius = 50,
     x = e.pageX - posX, /* Offset not sure if cross-browser compatibile? */
     y = e.pageY - posY,
     coords = {
        x:x,
        y:y
     };

     function findDist( start, end ){
       var dx = end.x;
       var dy = end.y;

       dx -= start.x;
       dx *= dx;

       dy -= start.y;
       dy *= dy;

       return Math.sqrt( dx + dy );
     }

     sideA = findDist(coords,{x:radius,y:0}); /* Click to Top Circle */
     sideB = findDist(coords,{x:radius,y:radius}); /* Click to Center */
     sideC = radius; /* Center to Middle */

     function findAngleUsingSides(a, b, c) {  
        var radians = ((a * a) + (b * b) - (c * c)) / (2 * (a * b));
        return (Math.acos(radians))/ Math.PI * 180;
     }

     A = findAngleUsingSides(sideB, sideC, sideA);

     if(x < radius){
        /* 
        You clicked before halfway across
        */
        A = 360 - A;
     }

     percentClicked =  A / 360;

     console.log(percentClicked);

});
```